# Unable to change the web address in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

So I am new to SharePoint 2013. I created a site page (web part page) and made that page into the homepage . Everything worked fine but when I click on the logo of the page it takes me back to my older homepage. I even went to site settings, Title description and logo to change the web address, however, it doesn’t allow the site pages to be on the web address. It doesn’t let me add “/“ to the url of web address so how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The logo URL is usually set in your master page. If you don't have access to SharePoint Designer or you want a less invasive approach, you can always try this option:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-a-different-page-for-your-sharepoint-site-home-page-35a5022c-f84a-455d-985e-c691ab5dfa17

Basically, you choose which page you want to be your home page. This might work for your situation.